# Error Response: "Unexpected token o in JSON at Position 1" using AWS SES, Lambda, Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ses

Don't really know how to resolve the following error. I'm trying to return a more detailed response when a user submits a contact-us form page submission via my website.

```
{
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1",
  "trace": [
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1",
    "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:6:53)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:74:25)"
  ]
}
```

The Lambda Function is as is:

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const ses = new aws.SES({ region: "us-east-1" });
exports.handler = async function (event) {
  console.log('EVENT: ', event)
    // Extract the properties from the event body
  const { senderEmail, senderName, message } = JSON.parse(event.body)
  const params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: ["your@email.com"],
    },
        // Interpolate the data in the strings to send
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Text: { 
            Data: `You just got a message from ${senderName} - ${senderEmail}:
            ${message}` 
        },
      },
      Subject: { Data: `Message from ${senderName}` },
    },
    Source: "your@email.com",
  };

  return ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
};
```

Comment: What does `console.log('EVENT: ', event)` show?

Comment: Make sure event.body contains those attributes. `const { senderEmail, senderName, message } = JSON.parse(event.body)`